# Analyzing ANR errors on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, google-chrome, webview

In the past week I've received 11 very similar ANRs for an app of mine. I've tried to analyze them but I fail to see which part of the code is causing the ANR.

Here's one of the stack dumps: http://pastebin.com/rC8f3fgr

I thought ANRs always were caused by something blocking the main thread. However in the dumps I can't even find the main thread of the app (com.degoo.android).

The only thing I find a bit suspicious is that several threads are waiting for something in libwebviewchromium.so. We don't use Chrome's webview for anything. However, we do support login via Google's OAuth-mechanism. Perhaps that is using the webview?

How should I go about analyzing problems like this?

Comment: are you using OkHttp  lib ?

Comment: *We don't use Chrome's webview for anything.* even AdView?

Comment: @dhams not directly. Perhaps some third-party dependency does.

Comment: @Selvin: nope, we don't show any ads at the moment.

Comment: you should start from decoding `c.a.a.a.a.c.m.a`, and others similar ...

Comment: @Selvin: c.a.a.a.a.c.m.a is part of the Fabric SDK. It's this class to be more precise: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityFutureTask

Comment: It looks like you're using Crashlytics from that dump. Can you match up and stack traces to when this happens?

Comment: @Heyyou: this is from a remote user's device. How do I access the logcat on that device?

Comment: @BrandonLerner: we haven't received any corresponding crash report in Crashalytics. In our next release we'll use ANR-WatchDog to make sure that the ANR gets reported to Crashalytics as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is where Strict mode comes into picture:

```
if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());
     }
```

Once you have enabled strict mode, the app will be stuck at the screen that puts more load on the UI thread.

[More here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Comment: Thanks, but we use that already. The problem is that I've never managed to reproduce it locally.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, ANRs are caused by deadlocks involving the UI thread. I guess you tried to synchronize the way your app uses a resource (like a data structure) before the ANRs started.

Best way I have to deal with ANRs:
1. Search for "synchronized (" (or "synchronized(") in your project (go to edit -> search in file if using Android Studio or search -> file in Eclipse).
2. Put some prints before, inside and after each synchronized block:

```
System.out.println("className.methodName() : capturing lock");
synchronized (lock) {
    System.out.println("className.methodName() : lock captured"); 
    ...
}
System.out.println("className.methodName() : lock released");
```

3. Run and wait for an ANR. The logs should give you all the data you need to know when and why this / these ANRs happen.

Be very careful when synchronizing methods that have synchronized blocks inside them --- this was the cause of the deadlock in my case, because then the UI thread can capture a class lock and wait for some lock to be released, but a thread that's supposed to release that lock waits for the general class level lock to be released, which is captured by the UI thread, hence a deadlock. If this is indeed the case, you may want to avoid synchronizing methods and instead rely solely on synchronized blocks.

Hope it helps :)